# How to create an android library project with no resources

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I want to create a library project with just java/Android classes - but no resources. Basically it will contain helpers for IO etc. I have manually deleted the resources etc - the project is [here](https://github.com/Utumno/AndroidHelpers) - but I wonder if this can be done out of the box - or is my way not proper
NB: I need Android classes - so creating a regular java project is not an option (?)

Edit : if there is no out of the box way is there any catch in deleting the (edit: contents of the) `res/` folder and the  support library ? I would appreciate a 1-2-3 procedure

Comment: In Properties -> Android, mark the "Is library" option.
In your project that will use the library, go to Properties -> Android, click in "Add.." and select your project, then, in Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects, click in "Add..." and add your library project again

Comment: I just forgot to add in my comment that I think you can't create an Android library project without the `/res` directory, as pointed by @KayvanN

Comment: You'll find some of the answers here: [Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a git repository to illustrate - I created a vanilla eclipse android library project ([screens](https://github.com/Utumno/EmptyAndroidLibrary/wiki/Eclipse-Wizards)) added a git ignore (`bin/`) and then proceeded to delete unneeded resources (all the contents of the `res/` folder) along with `libs/` and `assets/` and edit the manifest. The changes are in [this commit](https://github.com/Utumno/EmptyAndroidLibrary/commit/dab4aa9fd86570394623c1d7cbdd10dcb7faffc7) for reference. Cleaning the project removed `R.java` along.

Will be adding more (`.gitattributes` and eclipse settings for android) but this is for now.

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep project structure, incl. having `res/` foder with `drawable/` etc, but these folders can be empty. There's no requirement for your library to reference any drawable. 
Others suggest it's mandatory for "app icon" but your library does not need any `<application>` entry in manifest, so it does not need any icon. The same applies to `values/` and `layout/` folders. Your library project have to have these folders (as required by build process), but having no file in them (so basically keeping them empty) is perfectly fine and valid and meets your requirements.

Comment: I have deleted all the contents of the `res/` folder (no `drawable/` `values/` and `layout/` ) and my main project compiles alright

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should keep all the required folders (including res) but you can leave them empty. Here is a guide for it.
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot delete the res folder completely since the app icon is contained in it. However you can delete the default layout if you do not need it and any other content that is required for the app to work.

If you would like to access the Android classes you will have to create an Android project.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have deleted all the contents of the res folder - I have to keep the (empty) dir finally yes - but the app icon is useless to me - so how about a 1-2-3 procedure ?